# Ways to access a MessageSource without using MessageSourceAware in the Spring MVC framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, localization

I have couple of servlets designed to hold its own message source, but there is a single static function which uses this message source as backup and in normal case uses a global BDB to retrieve localized text.

I wanted to know if there is a way to retrieve the MessageSource for the context of the servlet which is calling this global static function ?

I can not use MessageSourceAware in all the servlets. I have looked into the Spring documentation and found MessageSourceAware and @autowired properties. I can not use the annotation because i am using spring 2.0.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Parth

Comment: What I meant was that if I go that way, then I have to make all of my servlets implement this interface for a functionality that is shared across all. I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your MessageSource is defined within your WebApplicationContext, you can retrieve it via:

```
WebApplicationContext webAppContext = RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request);
MessageSource messageSource = webAppContext.getBean("messageSource");
```

Comment: If you have no request, you can also do `WebApplicationContext webAppContext = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();`